# I want to send post request to server with parameter and get back data in JSON format in android

Tags: java, android, json

I want to send post request to server with parameters like email,api_id,api_key along with URL .
I am using the asyntask for performing background opertion but in doInbackground() method , ,when I debugging it show problem in doInbackground() .My Main class is

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://www.shotmakersgolf.com/server/api/user.login";

    // JSON Node names





    private static final String SUCCESS="success";
    private static final String TOKEN="token";
    private static final String TOKEN_EXPIRE="token_expire";
    private static final String LOGIN="login";
    private static final String LOGIN_STATUS="status";



    // contacts JSONArray

    JSONObject jsonObj;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();


        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you are in preexceute", 3000).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                      jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);



                    // looping through All Contacts


                        String id = jsonObj.getString(SUCCESS);
                        String name = jsonObj.getString(TOKEN);
                        String email = jsonObj.getString(TOKEN_EXPIRE);





                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject login = jsonObj.getJSONObject(LOGIN);
                        String mobile = login.getString(LOGIN_STATUS);


                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(SUCCESS, id);
                        contact.put(TOKEN, name);
                        contact.put(TOKEN_EXPIRE, email);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { SUCCESS, TOKEN,
                            TOKEN_EXPIRE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }



    }

}
```

My Servicehelper class is

```
public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;
    public ServiceHandler() {

    }


    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {


        try {
            // http client
            HttpClient  httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            System.out.print("you are correct");

            // Checking http request method type 

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "kramer@siosphere.com"));  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "testtest"));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_id", "3"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", "06875425-b293-43af-9966-3566045f6bb95b1f7c5e-f932-4916-87f5-db0b298f2"));


                // adding post params
                if (nameValuePairs != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);



            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);




        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem of doInbackground?

Comment: If you are already working with AsyncTaask then why you calling Service from it? You dont need to call Service actually.

Comment: Karthikeyan sir I am getting the foolowing error                   FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)

Comment: pratt sir ,I call Servicehandler from main class for http connectin

Comment: Nguyễn Hoài Nam  sir I am getting the foolowing error FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)

Comment: You forgot to tell which statement is on line 300.

Comment: Remove the Toast() from doInBackground(). It will cause the crash of your app. Moreover that's what's visible in the LogCat.

Comment: @greenapps i think (AsyncTask.java:300) states the error on the Android's sourcecode but not his code

Comment: I get the solution to my problem 

The problem is that ,I want to touch main thread from background thread .

Comment: I get the solution to my problem .The problem is that ,I want to touch main thread from background thread . 
In Asyntask a)onPreExecute(),onpostExecute() is works on main thread b)Doinbackground() Work on background Thread .